# What part of speech is "that" in this phrase?

Tags: parts-of-speech, which-that

I know that "that" can function as many different parts of speech, so what part of speech is it in the phrase "the stuff that dreams are made of"?

Answer (score 2):

ODO believes it to be a relative pronoun:

> **that** *pronoun* (*plural **those***)
>   **5** (plural **that**) [*relative pronoun*] used to introduce a defining clause, especially one essential to identification:
>   • instead of ‘which’, ‘who’, or ‘whom’:
>      *the woman that owns the place*
>   • instead of ‘when’ after an expression of time:
>      *the year that Anna was born*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/that)

The example “instead of *which, who* or *whom*” exactly matches your sentence.

Comment: It's perhaps worth adding that not all linguists consider _that_ to be a relative pronoun.

Comment: @BarrieEngland I had hoped that the first line indicated that. I've never really understood subtlety! But I have altered it and it does mean there is scope for a different answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

"That" introduces a sentence complement to a noun, as in "the fact that we left", where the sentence "we left" is complement to "fact".  When the complement is a relative clause, there is a common alternative analysis that makes "that" a relative pronoun, yet this is not right, because relative pronouns need not occur at the beginning of a relative clause.  "That" in relative clauses, unlike relative pronouns, always comes at the very beginning of the clause.  Compare, "the facts with which we are familiar", *"the facts with that we are familiar", "the facts that we are familiar with".